# I can't find my mistake in a "Codeforces" problem

Tags: java, logic

The question is- https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/231/A
I was pretty sure I found the right solution in Java and it worked properly when I tried it, but when I submitted it, it said error in test 1. It would be a great help if someone can point out the mistake. My coide is below:

```
import java.util.*;
public class A_Team {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Number of Question: ");
        int count = 0;
        int loop = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
            int arr[] = new int[3];
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                arr[j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            if(arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] >= 2){
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

**Note:** Please don't ask to change the language, I am new to programing and I only know bits of C and Java only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually these code challenges don't want you to print anything but the answer. They are usually judged or graded by automated software that is looking for an answer in a precise format. Remove `System.out.println("Enter Number of Question: ");`

Answer (score 0):

1. n or in your case the *loop* should be 1 ≤ n ≤ 1000 so check that
2. The forj loop has the same length as the array loop so you could declare a constant above or use the array length. So you doesen't have to change it twice if needed.
3. Use the Arrays class if you need methods for arrays like to sum (Arrays.stream(arr).sum()).

   ```
    public class A_Team {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Number of Question: ");
        int count = 0;
        int loop = sc.nextInt();
        //1.
        if (1 <= loop && loop <= 1000) {
            for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
                int[] arr = new int[3];
                //2.
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                    arr[j] = sc.nextInt();
                }
                //3.
                int sum = Arrays.stream(arr).sum();
                if (sum >= 2) {
                    count += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Nice suggestions. Are there any reasons to believe that they will change the program output and make the automatic test pass?

Comment: I guess the int n/loop is the problem so the if should solve this @OleV.V.

Comment: @xthe_white_lionx  Although the advice was good, I don't see how it can help. Imagine loop is not in that range, then what? It just prints count, which is 0. Of course your addition makes the code more clear but that was not the issue.